# Can't edit static assets while application is running

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, grizzly

While my application is running, I'm not able to save static assets that are being served.  This is kind of a pain for debugging as I'd like to just be able to refresh the page when editing css, js and html.

I thought that the line `listener.getFileCache().setEnabled(false);` below would do the trick, but it still won't let me edit these files.  Is there something else I missed in the configuration?

[image]

Here's my application...

```
    final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(".", 8181);

    WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("Socket", "/");

    //enable annotation configuration
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "com.production");

    //allow spring to do all of it's stuff
    ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");

    //enable web socket support
    final WebSocketAddOn addon = new WebSocketAddOn();
    for (NetworkListener listener : server.getListeners()) {
        listener.registerAddOn(addon);

        //if false, local files (html, etc.) can be modified without restarting the server
        listener.getFileCache().setEnabled(false);
    }

    //add jersey servlet support
    //@todo add spring support to jersey
    ServletRegistration jerseyServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new ServletContainer());
    jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.production.resource");
    jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    jerseyServletRegistration.addMapping("/api/*");

    //add atmosphere servlet support
    AtmosphereServlet atmosphereServlet = new AtmosphereServlet();
    AtmosphereFramework f = atmosphereServlet.framework();

    ReflectorServletProcessor r = new ReflectorServletProcessor();
    r.setServletClassName("com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet");

    f.addAtmosphereHandler("/socket/*", r);

    ServletRegistration atmosphereServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("AtmosphereServlet", atmosphereServlet);
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("org.atmosphere.websocket.messageContentType", "application/json");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.production.resource");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    //atmosphereServletRegistration.addMapping("/socket/*");
    atmosphereServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    //serve static assets
    StaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/web");
    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/");
```

**Update:**

I ended up migrating my AngularJS application outside of the java world due to the nature of AngularJS not needing to be a part of the java project.

Comment: one more thing you can try:
networkListener.setSendFileEnabled(false);

Comment: Does it affect any editor or only IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @alexey Thanks, but that didn't fix it :-\

Comment: @CrazyCoder I don't know, I don't use any other editors

Comment: Do you see this behavior only when the server is started? If yes, do you see this behavior right after the server is started before you made the first request to the file?